# htaccess https to https subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'm creating a puzzle/challenge website that requires there to be two different sets of served files, depending on whether or not the user typed http: or https:

It doesn't seem like I can just redirect all HTTPS traffic using my web-host to a subfolder, so I've been trying to edit the htaccess file, but I keep ending up with infinite redirects.

What I'm trying to do:

```
http://www.example.com/secure   ->   http://www.example.com 
https://www.example.com         ->   https://www.example.com/secure
```

When I setup redirects, after chrome times out, I get https://www.example.com/secure/secure/secure/secure/secure/secure/secure ...

The redirects I've setup are:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/secure [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure/ http://www.example.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Neither rule seems to work, but the first rule seems to loop forever. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to redirect users or you just want to serve two different sets of files?

Comment: Ideally I'd serve two completely different sites from the same host. Unfortunately, I don't have any ability to edit the apache configuration. The website is part of a puzzle where https and http should behave differently. (edited because accidentally hit enter before finishing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}` on portion may not work for all web servers. Some of servers are using `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https`.

I think you should do :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/secure [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secure
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, it directs all https traffic to http.

Comment: After playing around with this for a while, I was able to get it to work by changing the !https in the second group to http  and by adding RewriteEngine On above the https off line. If you make those changes I'll mark it solved. ---- Thanks :)